# Excel spreadsheet check two conditions along different rows & columns

Tags: excel

Hey I'm really stuck on this one, basically tying to get a result of either 'hired' or 'available' (or 0 & 1 to represent) in B2, of BOTH the two conditions in B1 & A2, looking at the log table A6:B10 of when they are 'hired out'. I've tried VLOOKUP and many IF functions but neither quite work correctly.

[image: Spreadsheet example]

Comment: It's just showing separation. The actual log table (A6:B10) is on a different sheet.

Comment: never mind .. I misunderstood. A2 and B1 are used for input and B2 as output. You can search for something like "double lookup" https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2012/04/26/using-multiple-criteria-in-excel-lookup-formulas/

Answer (score 1):

One option here, though perhaps not the most graceful, would be to use `VLOOKUP` with the car and date as the key.  The issue here is that there are multiple lookup values, namely the car and the particular date.  To get around this, you could create a new column `C` which contains the concatenated car and date, e.g.

```
      A  |     B      |        C         | D
 6 Car 1 | 03-01-2017 | Car 1 03-01-2017 | 0
 7 Car 2 | 03-01-2017 | Car 2 03-01-2017 | 0
 8 Car 3 | 04-01-2017 | Car 3 04-01-2017 | 0
 9 Car 4 | 05-01-2017 | Car 4 05-01-2017 | 0
10 Car 2 | 06-01-2017 | Car 2 06-01-2017 | 0
```

To create column `C`, simply enter the following formula into cell `C6` and then copy it down the entire column:

```
=CONCATENATE(A6, " ", B6)
```

Now you can use the following `VLOOKUP` formula in cell `B2` to calculate whether a given ride is available on a certain date:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&" "&B1,C6:D10,2,FALSE), 1)
```

Here I have hard-coded in column `D` the value `0` for every entry, to represent that these are rides which are already hired-out for that particular car and date.  If our `VLOOKUP` formula finds a match, then it means the ride is hired-out.  If `VLOOKUP` does not find a match, it would throw an error, in which case we display `1` to indicate availability.

Comment: Thanks Tim that would definitely work, and I can simply have it on a hidden sheet. But would there be an easy way for it to automatically generate this new column C because otherwise it would be alot of extra work ?

Comment: @DeathGrip Yes, just enter column `C` as a formula, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: Ahhh yea right, I didn't know that function. Awesome! I'll play around with that setup and see how it all works, thanks for your time!!